# How can Views show logged in user?

Tags: views, users

To create a friend list I'm using views with a "user relationship". It's working fine. Now I want an extra field with the information of who is logged in.

I saw the "filter criteria" to show only the logged in user, but I only want this as a field and maybe in the "sort criteria".  How can I achieve this? I'm a little confused!

Comment: Bruno, which version of Drupal are you using? Views are different in Drupal 6 and 7.  In general, it always helps to tag the correct version of Drupal you have or specify that info in the question...

Comment: Do you mean that you want a field that says if the user is currently logged-in? Differently, you want a field that shows the username.

Comment: I`m using Drupal 7. I need an extra field for the currently logged-in user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How obtain the uid of the logged user as a related field in a view?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173950/how-obtain-the-uid-of-the-logged-user-as-a-related-field-in-a-view)