# How obtain the uid of the logged user as a related field in a view?

Tags: 7, views, users

I have a view showing the nodes of a content type, and I want to show the user ID of the currently logged-in user as a field in view, but I can't find how to add the user ID of the currently logged-in user. I know that I can achieve this with the [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module but I want to know if there is another way.

I have [Views 3.11](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

There is no relation between the content being shown, and the currently logged-in user; I just want to show the user ID of the user who is currently seeing the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without some custom module providing such a data field (such as views php as you've seen).

Unless the uid has some relations to the content type you're displaying (e.g. a user reference field, the node uid, etc.), there's no way to retrieve the current UID. Views is designed to pull in data from a base table (e.g. nodes, users, taxonomy, etc.) and display the fields directly attached to it or related to it through a relationship.

Comment: thanks Shawn, I think that the sareed comment http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/30335/sareed is a way too. But the uid of the logged user I think that is a global var, I can't understand  why this is not possible

Comment: It is possible, just not with Views alone. Maybe there is a module that creates view fields from contextual filter values, I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a good idea, I will search about this

Comment: There is an alternative to Views PHP. All you have to do is override the view template file, which allows you to use php there. I can provide a detailed answer if you are still interested.

Comment: @NoSssweat I know that way, but if you want add other answer for other users go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of *relationships* in views by choosing `content:author`. This will give you uid [get_uid](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18628/how-do-relationships-work-in-views).

Other way of achieving this is by using [views php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) filter.
Views php field with code should do the job:

```
<?php
  global $user; 
  print $user->uid; 
?>
```

Comment: both the options from your answer don't give solution related to question. **1)** In your first option uid will be visible only if logged in user has created some content. If user has not created any content then it's uid will not be shown in views.
**2)** In your 2nd option you suggest *views php* but in question this is clearly mentioned that OP wants an other functionality except of views php.

Comment: I know the way with views_php actually this is the code that I have. But if I can't use views_php is better for me

Answer (score 0):

The uid of the current user as a field in view would be the same for each row of your view results, so I am presuming some other outcome than merely displaying this field.

My guess would be to use it as a rewrite rule to create a link that has the user id in it (I'm struggling to come up with another scenario - perhaps specify?)

For that use-case, I would use custom php field - it's the simplest. It does sound like you are looking for a contextual filter, rather. Set the default value to be the uid of the logged in user.

Comment: I need this value to make a comparison with views_conditional